# Haskell: Why is my implementation of the Fibonacci sequence inefficient?

Tags: haskell, fibonacci, memoization

I have written the following Fibonacci play program as part of learning Haskell:

```
fibonacci 0 = [0]       
fibonacci 1 = [0,1]          
fibonacci n = let   
                foo'1 = last (fibonacci (n-1))
                foo'2 = last (fibonacci (n-2))
              in  reverse((foo'1 + foo'2):reverse (fibonacci (n-1)))
```

The program works:

```
ghci>fibonacci 6
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
```

But, the performance goes down exponentially with n.  If I give it an argument of 30 it takes about a minute to run as opposed to running instantaneously at 6. It seems the lazy execution is burning me and fibonacci is getting run once for every element in the final list.

Am I doing something silly or missing something?

(I already got rid of the ++ thinking that might be doing it)

Comment: This looks like a textbook example of where [memoization](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) becomes helpful.

Comment: You are making _three_ recursive calls when _one_ would suffice. I'd write `reverseFib` to return the Fibonacci numbers in the reverse direction, since that's easier. Once that is defined, you can define `fibonacci = reverse . reverseFib` so that you reverse the list only once at the end. (Of course, there are other well-known approaches in Haskell, e.g. recursion on lists instead of functions... but forget about these for the moment)

Comment: I think the memoization is the key here since I keep recalculating the list every time I want to reference one of the members.  I'll check it out! (Hah!  I see the recursive example uses the Fibonacci sequence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your approach is a tad overcomplicated. In particular, you don't need to use recursive calls, or even the `reverse` function, in order to generate the Fibonacci sequence.

#### A linear-time implementation

In addition to [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681945/2541573), here is a textbook one-liner, which uses memoization:

```hs
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Once you have `fibs`, writing your `fib` function is trivial:

```hs
fib :: Int -> [Integer]
fib n
    | n < 0     = error "fib: negative argument"
    | otherwise = take (n+1) fibs
```

This implementation of `fib` has complexity Θ(n), which is obviously much better than Θ(exp(n)).

#### Test in GHCi

```hs
λ> :set +s
λ> fib 6
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
(0.02 secs, 7282592 bytes)
λ> fib 30
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368,75025,121393,196418,317811,514229,832040]
(0.01 secs, 1035344 bytes)
```

As you can see, `fib 30` is evaluated in well under one minute on my machine.

#### Further reading

For a much more comprehensive treatment of how to generate the Fibonacci sequence in Haskell, I refer you to this [haskell.org wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence)

Comment: That is elegant! Wow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to the question using @icktoofay's pointer to [memoization](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization).  The answer included a function that quickly returned a given fibonacci number, so I used their example to create a solution to my original problem--creating a list of the Fibonacci numbers up to the requested number.

This solution runs pretty much instantaneously (the page has the additional benefit of referring to my approach as "naive")

```
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)

fib 0 = [0]
fib 1 = [0,1]
fib n = reverse ((memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib(n-1)) : reverse (fib (n-1)))
```

Comment: `fib n = map memoized_fib [0..n]`.

Comment: Sigh...this old PERL brain is having paradigm shift problems. (Nice one!)

Comment: not "how to do it", but "what it is"... this gives me an idea: `reverse` should really have been named `reversed`. check out also `inits` and `tails` from Data.List if you haven't already. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *add* memoization to your function - it already has all the previous results, producing a list as it does. You just need to stop *ignoring* those results, as you do right now using `last`.

First of all, if it's more natural to build the list in reverse order, there's no reason not to:

```
revFib 0 = [0]       
revFib 1 = [1,0]          
revFib n | n > 0 = let  f1 = head (revFib (n-1))
                        f2 = head (revFib (n-2))
                   in  f1 + f2 : revFib (n-1)
```

This is still slow, as we're still ignoring all the previous results except the very last one, situated at the head of the list. We can stop doing that,

```
revFib 0 = [0]       
revFib 1 = [1,0]          
revFib n | n > 0 = let  f1 = head (revFib (n-1))
                        f2 = head (tail (revFib (n-1)))
                   in  f1 + f2 : revFib (n-1)
```

and then we'll name the common subexpression, so that it is shared among its uses, and is only calculated once:

```
revFib 0 = [0]       
revFib 1 = [1,0]          
revFib n | n > 0 = let  prevs = revFib (n-1)
                        [f1,f2] = take 2 prevs
                   in  f1 + f2 : prevs
```

and suddenly it's linear instead of *exponential*.